# CheckBoxList.Selected keeps coming back with False value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkboxlist

I have a CheckBoxList on my page that isn't behaving very well.

The idea is that once the submit button on the form is clicked, the app should clear the database table of all rows pertaining to the specific user and then re-insert new ones based on the user's CheckBoxList selections.

The problem is that regardless of whether or not any (or all) items in the CheckBoxList are selected, the app keeps getting `Selected = False`.

Here's my code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    loadRegions()
End Sub

Private Sub loadRegions()

    Dim db As New Database

    Dim sql As String = "select * from regions"

    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = db.execDB(sql, "Text", Nothing, "DataReader", False)

    If dr.HasRows Then

        cblRegion.DataSource = dr
        cblRegion.DataTextField = "regionname"
        cblRegion.DataValueField = "regionid"
        cblRegion.DataBind()
    End If

    dr.Close()
End Sub

Protected Sub btnRegister_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRegister.Click
        ' ============================================================
        ' There's more code in here, but it's irrelevant to this paste
        ' ============================================================

        Dim sql As String = "delete from userregions where userid = " & lblUserID.Text & ";"

        For i As Integer = 0 To cblRegion.Items.Count - 1
            If cblRegion.Items(i).Selected Then
                sql &= "insert into userregions (userid, regionid)" & _
                    "values(" & UserID & ", " & cblRegion.Items(i).Value & ")"

                db.execDB(sql, "Text", Nothing, "None", False)
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

**For the record**
I'm aware of the potential for SQL Injection here. I'll be going over to using Parameters as soon as I have the loop working.

Thanks for your time.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to call `loadRegions` on the initial load and not on postbacks:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        loadRegions()
    End If
End Sub
```

Otherwise you'll lose changed values and events are not triggered.

Comment: oh for heaven's sake... I've been staring at this for almost an hour and never bothered to check... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In page loaded, write the following:

```
If Not IsPostBack
    loadRegions()
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line of copde "If IsPostBack Then Return" in Page_Load method.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If IsPostBack Then Return
    loadRegions()
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm fairly embarrassed about the simplicity of this answer... Fact is I never even thought that the data bind should go in a postback... Guess my brain decided I could afford to skip that step

Comment: It happened a lot to us too when we started writing code in .Net. I couldn't figure out when data were always being stored with the first or default values.